# How to read transaction['data'] from getTransaction

Tags: web3js

How does one read transaction['data']? If I get the data of a transaction e.g. something like this:

> 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

This is what I found out so far:

0xe8e337 means it is a liquidity event

Token contracts that were added as liquidity:
55d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955
c9882def23bc42d53895b8361d0b1edc7570bc6a

Liquidity provider wallet:
b06bf7329fcecba4cdcba074c02c62d5566fd51a

(1) What information can be gathered from the rest? E.g. what does "5c46e1a550c42" mean?
(2) Is there a spreadsheet with different event identifiers? E.g. "0xf305d719" seems to be another liquidity event, but I can only identify the liquidity provider and the token, not a second liquidity token:

> 0xf305d719000000000000000000000000c42ec65f615e6fc8e57dcc37bd74a3162ae8fa3700000000000000000000000000000000000000000000298c48498d2ff6e0ad6f000000000000000000000000000000000000000000002921eb6789372a2b3b0f00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000599360101baa420000000000000000000000008e8b94683ee3decfb25e54e0230c4d347ded28370000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061d0f425

Where c42ec65f615e6fc8e57dcc37bd74a3162ae8fa37 is the token contract and 8e8b94683ee3decfb25e54e0230c4d347ded2837 is the liquidity provider.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is parsed as follows. Next, you need to look at the specification of the specific contract where the data was sent.

```
function e8e33700
address  00000000000000000000000055d398326f99059ff775485246999027b3197955
address  000000000000000000000000c9882def23bc42d53895b8361d0b1edc7570bc6a
number   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c46e1a550c420000
number   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f8502a
number   000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000005c2f4230287e4c000
number   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001f7cf10
address  000000000000000000000000b06bf7329fcecba4cdcba074c02c62d5566fd51a
number   0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000061d0ef84
```

Comment: That's a very clean way of formatting. Thank you. I figured it's a hex number, but when I convert them they don't match with any values in the liquidity event. What do these numbers mean? Also, do you know of an overview or spreadsheet with all the different functions?

Comment: What standard does the contract to which the transaction was sent correspond to?

Comment: I am using ether.js to get the transaction data. Is that what you are referring to?

Comment: In order to understand the meaning of a particular transaction parameter, you either need to have a contract code, or know which interface standard it supports (for example, ERC20). Otherwise, it will be very difficult to understand what these or those numbers mean.